# Using Knex to update a table column with the current timestamp

Tags: node.js, express, knex.js

Im using Node.js and Knex for my back end API and im trying to update a table with the current timestamp.

```
currentTime = new Date().toISOString();

db('_sessions')
        .where({
          sessionkey: apiKey
        })
        .select()
        .then(function(resp) {
          var sessionStart = new Date(resp[0].sessionstart);
          var sessionLast = new Date(resp[0].sessionlast);
          var allowableTime = resp[0].alloweddurationseconds;
          var currentTime = sessionLast.getTime() - sessionStart.getTime();
          var minutesDifference = Math.floor(currentTime/1000);

          if (minutesDifference < allowableTime) {
            db('_sessions')
              .where({
                sessionkey: resp[0].sessionkey
              })
              .returning('sessionlast')
              .update({sessionlast: currentTime})

            resolve({
              securitycheck: true,
              userID: resp[0].userid,
              accountID: resp[0].accountid,
            })
          } else {
            resolve({
              securitycheck: false,
              userID: 0,
              accountID: 0,
            })
          }
        })
```

Thge update query for some reason isnt updating the column in the database?

Comment: Is `db.fn.now()` `undefined`?

Comment: Not sure it returns a huge object, however i dont believe this is the best way to go about this.

Comment: For `postgres` this works: `knex('table_name').update({ updated_at: 'now' })` . Or you can try `.update({ some_timestamp: knex.raw('now()') })` to be more obvious

Comment: are you trying to update a row in the table or change the column name based off the time?

Answer (score 0):

```
.update({sessionlast:  db.fn.now()})
```

or

```
.update({sessionlast:  knex.fn.now()})
```

should work.